# org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet working with #

Tags: java, http-get

I use httpclient 4.1.2 library for handling requests.
The question is simple - how to handle situations when server changes get request URI header.
I face this firstly:
1) I sent get request :

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(nextRequest);
response = httpclient.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
...
```

From debug window I saw the uri : "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4464735&.."

2) In the same time from WireShark program I coud see following

```
"172.16.2.28","95.213.4.228","HTTP","312","GET /blank.html#access_token=de0ec1b94fbf09b8b9a0f2c2d52465bc1b2627489b34c4b6be091a3136804930e62d5d964cd5e2fce3c79&expires_in=86400&user_id=228506529 HTTP/1.1 "
```

for the same request I got 2 different headers. How could it be? And how can I get the part which starts with "# " from URI programmatically? HttpGet object still holds old `URI(get.getURI().toString()`) ?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think the 1st URL is redirecting to another URL , and you are getting the result for another url

Comment: Yes, maybe this happens, but how to get this new Url in java?  HttpGet object still holds old URI.